# How do I get what is inside the quotaion using regex_search

Tags: c++, regex

I was trying to get the text inside the double qoutaion. So far, I was only able to print with the qoutation. I am using regex_search.

**file.txt**

```
"Life is Hard, stay calm." - someone
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    ifstream fOpen("file.txt");
    string line0;
    getline(fOpen,line0);
    regex pattern2("(.*) -.*");
    smatch matcher;
    regex_search(line0, matcher, pattern2);
    cout<<matcher[1]<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

output so far

```
"Life is Hard, stay calm."
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: I don't see how this can reproducible, given that your regex pattern `(.*) -.*` does not match the output shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this:  `\"([^\"]*)\"`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/DqnIiq/6) here

Code:

```
int main(){
    ifstream fOpen("file.txt");
    string line0;
    getline(fOpen,line0);
    regex pattern2("\"([^\"]*)\"");
    smatch matcher;
    regex_search(line0, matcher, pattern2);
    cout<<matcher[1]<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```